# How to implement cosmos rating controller in IOS?

Tags: cosmos

I am new to IOS development. I am trying to use rating functionality in my app, found cosmos controller but i do not understand how to use its functionality.Please help me and let me know if any sample project is available.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drag & drop UIView in your xib file. Set the class to CosmosView and the module to Cosmos and the rest is very easy.